How to draw momentum arrows using tikzfeynman.sty?
I am using tikzfeynman.sty written by Flip Tanedo to draw Feynman diagrams. A sample code that I wrote--
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1.5 pt, scale=1.3]
    \draw[scalar] (45:1.5)--(0,0);
    \draw[scalarbar] (135:1.5)--(0,0);
    \draw[vector] (225:1.5)--(0,0);
    \draw[vector] (315:1.5)--(0,0);
    \node at (45:1.7) {$\phi$};
    \node at (135:1.7) {$\phi^\dagger$};
    \node at (225:1.7) {$A_\mu$};
    \node at (315:1.7) {$A_\nu$};
    \draw[->, line width=0.8pt] (55:1.2) -- (66:0.5) node[midway, above] {$p^1$};
    \draw[->, line width=0.8pt] (145:1.2) -- (155:0.5) node[midway, below] {$p^2$};
    \draw[->, line width=0.8pt] (235:1.2) -- (250:0.5) node[midway, below] {$p^3$};
    \draw[->, line width=0.8pt] (325:1.2) -- (340:0.5) node[midway, above] {$p^4$};
    \end{tikzpicture}

The result of this is the following-

As one can notice, for the momentum arrows I used trail and error method to determine its positions. So there lies my problem-- can anyone please suggest some better way of doing this? I don't want to use Tikz-Feynman which I know has a very simple and elegant way of doing this (I don't like the style of arrow there and don't know how to change the same). May be a similar type (as for the case of Tikz-Feynman) of implementation here (tikzfeynman.sty) will be nice!
Any help regarding this is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72914767/tikz-feynman-making-a-diagram-with-no-horizontal-propagator
